# unable to login using docker registry on jenkins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, docker-registry, aws-ecr

I have a Jenkinsfile that I need to login to ECR. this is the relevant section

```
        script {
          docker.withRegistry('https://01234.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/', 'awsId'){
            def image = docker.image("01234.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/tas/master-server:${env.BUILD_ID}")
            image.push()
          }
```

But what gets output in the jenkins build is the strange part

```
$ docker login -u AKIAZWB**********HET -p ******** https://01234.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://01234.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/v2/ failed with status: 401 Unauthorized
```

I remember if one runs `aws ecr get-login` the `-u` is AWS, not the access key of the credentials. So where do I get this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are doing wrong is the way you specify the credentialID to be used.

Instead of `'awsId'` try to use `'ecr:ap-southeast-1:awsId'`

```
docker.withRegistry('https://01234.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/', 'ecr:ap-southeast-1:awsId') {
    def image = docker.image("01234.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/tas/master-server:${env.BUILD_ID}")
    image.push()                                        
}
```

EDIT: Check the [plugin doc](https://plugins.jenkins.io/amazon-ecr/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```java
script {
    sh "`aws ecr get-login --region ap-southeast-1 --no-include-email`"
    docker.image('01234.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/<yourImage>:<yourTag>')
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain _why_ one should use this instead? Thanks!

Comment: easy to use, based on known aws cli ecr api syntax